# ember-cli won't parse jquery/src/intro.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

i'm using ember-cli version 0.1.15 and it fails to run a newly created ember app.

Here are the commands issued to install ember-cli and to create the new app:

```
$ npm uninstall -g ember-cli
$ npm cache clean
$ bower cache clean
$ npm install -g ember-cli@0.1.15
$ ember new Query
$ cd Query
$ ember serve
```

While the ember service starts up, it attempts to parse the jquery intro.js file which is a partial module file because it does not close the IIFE function. I guess the outro.js file is the companion file that closes the intro.js.

Below is the resulting error after invoking `ember serve`

```
version: 0.1.15
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200/
File: bower_components/jquery/src/intro
Unexpected token (45:0)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (45:0)
    at raise (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:333:15)
        at unexpected (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1366:5)
    at parseExprAtom (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:2153:7)
    at parseExprSubscripts (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:2012:28)
    at parseMaybeUnary (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1995:16)
    at parseExprOps (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1946:24)
    at parseMaybeConditional (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1930:16)
    at parseMaybeAssign (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1913:16)
    at parseExpression (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1898:16)
    at parseStatement (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1586:38)
    at parseBlock (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1826:18)
    at parseFunctionBody (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:2378:19)
    at parseFunction (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:2277:5)
    at parseExprAtom (/Users/Steffen/Temp/Query/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6modules/node_modules/esperanto/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:2141:14)
```

I tried reinstalling ember-cli and clearing the npm and bower caches. Any other caches that need to be cleared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not capitalizing the new ember app's name:

```
ember new query
```

Also, you don't need to specify the ember cli version:

```
npm install -g ember-cli
```

In case *query* is a reserved keyword, if you still get errors, try another name.

Comment: creating a new ember app named "query" ended in the same problems. When I tried a different name like "qta" the ember serve command ran successfully. Thank you for the tip!